# Load file in java with special path name

Tags: java, windows, escaping, media-player

i try to play an mp3 from an location on my harddrive.

The file is located in here:

> C:\Itunes\Music\Eminem\The Eminem Show [Explicit]\18 'Till I Collapse [Explicit].mp3

There are a lot of special characters in this path like [ and '. When i try to load the file with following code:

```
path = URLEncoder.encode(path, "UTF-8");
Media hit = new Media("file:///"+path);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

i get an "illegal character" error in pathname.

My operating system is windows 8.

I'm very new to java and hope i find some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to encode your URI

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows.aspx

Comment: I do not understand what you want me to say. I try to load an URI from the Filepath like file.toUri() and load the path from the uri to the mediaplayer. It doenst work.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not read your code very well! Is the Media constructor throwing the error? Or is the URLEncoder throwing it?

Comment: I think its actually the Media constructor throwing the error. Check this [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media%28java.lang.String%29) out. It would appear that the URI you tried to use is not rfc2396 compliant, ish... If you go to page 10 [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), you will see that square braces are listed as 'unwise'. I would try simply printing out the escaped path and double checking that all the odd characters are indeed escaped.

Comment: C%3A%5CItunes5CMusic%5CEminem%5CThe+Eminem+Show+%5BExplicit%5D%5C18+%27Till+I+Collapse+%5BExplicit%5D.mp3

that is my encoded file path. Encoded with UTF-8.

Comment: Do you have any additional info on the error? Stack trace?

Comment: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\Itunes\Music\Eminem\The Eminem Show [Explicit]\18 'Till I Collapse [Explicit].mp3

i only get this error msg

Comment: Ah, you are using backslashes! Instead of \ to separate directories, use `File.separatorChar`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar) for the documentation. Your current code doesn't work because \ is used to escape characters. If you want the literal \ char, you need to put \\ inside a string.